# Adding UINavigationController to xCode Tab Bar Application Template

Tags: ios4, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

How to add UINavigationController to xCode Tab Bar Application Delegate?

My structure is based on xCode Tab Bar Application Delegate, with 2 tabs, First View & Second View respectively. For First View, I added a UITableView. I just want to make use of UINavigationController function `[self.navigationController pushViewController:animated:]` to push a subview and allow a navigation bar to be shown in subview. After pushing the subview, the tab bar must still be there.

Sounds simple, but I have no idea how to achieve it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with a Window-based template instead and did this to achieve the same thing.

I created my `NavigationControllers` and `TabBarController` in my app delegate manually.

In your:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Add this:

```
//Seeting up the Navigation controllers and pushing our TableView controllers.  
UINavigationController *unvc1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *unvc2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[unvc1 pushViewController:someViewController1 animated:NO];
[unvc2 pushViewController:someViewController2 animated:NO];
[someViewController1 release];[someViewController2 release];//Releasing our TableView controllers. 

//Setting up the TabBar controller and pushing our Navigation controllers. 
UITabBarController *tbvc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tbvc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:unvc1, unvc2, nil];
[unvc1 release];[unvc2 release]; //releasing our Navigation controllers.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: is there an Interface Builder solution?

Comment: Definitely, but unfortunately I haven't work with that template so I set it up like that. I know this isn't exactly what you wanted but it will help you to move forward. Additionally, any `ViewController` being pushed into the `NavigationController` and consequently the `TabBarConrtoller`, can be created with IB.

Answer (score 1):

I did this using presentModalViewController:animated . I added tabBar Controller in the modalView. In the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath use this presentModalViewController:animated .I might not be perfect but I had the same problem, but now my app works as I need.